# PHP Regex: extracting dynamic url from page body html

Tags: php, regex

I loaded a websites html onto a string and it has several `g.load()` code in the body - maybe around 10. I need this particular one which has an identifier of `divId:"listing-provided-by-module"`.

```
g.load({ajaxURL:"/AjaxRender.htm?encparams=4~502222143586867513~LVuCHKHFeed3jCcefsa9MDj3xIs5wDqP7UwvtV3XDO0HnrynNRzT338AKMnzqNa4bTpgvQbff_Phk5wkav9LlWUqZfiIFKl3zXnXawc1_XDPR_9F83BlTaqhCqbfubm40s0ZciFJZV2dHzDDwlDVJJzitcXFgThESVdjnWUjJkj_MuZSVclGh7ddZ0neIHCH&rwebid=46328989&rhost=1",jsModule:"z-complaint-manager-async-block",phaseType:"scroll",divId:"listing-provided-by-module"});
```

What I need exactly is the ajaxURL and at the same time it checks that it is indeed with `divId:"listing-provided-by-module"` so it gets the correct url. Hope you can help with the regex and PHP for this. Thanks!

I've tried:

```
/g\.load\(\{ajaxURL:"(.*)".*divId:"listing-provided-by-module"/
```

But the match is too wide.

Here is the whole HTML body I want to match against: http://pastebin.com/seJd2jjc

Comment: This is the whole html to extract the url from above: http://pastebin.com/seJd2jjc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ([visualized here](https://regex101.com/r/xP9uX2/3)):

```
'/g\.load\(\{ajaxURL:"([^"]*)",[^})]*,divId:"listing-provided-by-module"/s'
```

Your URL will be contained in the first capture group.

So, the PHP code would be:

```
<?php

$matches = [];
if (preg_match('/g\.load\(\{ajaxURL:"([^"]*)",[^})]*,divId:"listing-provided-by-module"/s', $string, $matches))
{
    $url = $matches[1];
}
else
{
    // No match found.
}
```

Comment: Hi this is the exact html - http://pastebin.com/seJd2jjc tried your code but I was not able to extract the g.load{} with the listing-provided-by-module

Comment: Thanks for providing that. Fixed, and updated the link to visualize it matching against your full HTML at the Regex101 link.